# How to use the google-api-services-plus-v1 without appengine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-api-java-client

I want to use the google-api-services-plus-v1 lib in a java console application but I get a ClassDefFoundError whenever I execute the following code:

```
Plus.Activities.Search req = service.activities().search(q); 
ActivityFeed feed = req.execute();
```

Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/appengine/api/urlfetch/HTTPMethod
at com.google.api.client.extensions.appengine.http.UrlFetchTransport.buildRequest(UrlFetchTransport.java:125)
```

How do I add these libraries?

Answer (score 2):

You are using the google-api-java-client distribution for AppEngine :

The following are the jars from the dependencies folder required for Servlet applications (or a newer compatible version of each dependency):

```
google-api-client-1.17.0-rc.jar
google-api-client-servlet-1.17.0-rc.jar
google-oauth-client-1.17.0-rc.jar
google-oauth-client-servlet-1.17.0-rc.jar
google-http-client-1.17.0-rc.jar
commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
gson-2.1.jar
httpclient-4.0.3.jar
httpcore-4.0.1.jar
jackson-core-asl-1.9.4.jar
jackson-core-2.1.3.jar
jdo2-api-2.3-eb.jar
jsr305-1.3.9.jar
protobuf-java-2.2.0.jar
transaction-api-1.1.jar
xpp3-1.1.4c.jar
```

For general purpose (command line) :

```
google-api-client-1.17.0-rc.jar
google-oauth-client-1.17.0-rc.jar
google-http-client-1.17.0-rc.jar
commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
gson-2.1.jar
httpclient-4.0.3.jar
httpcore-4.0.1.jar
jackson-core-asl-1.9.4.jar
jackson-core-2.1.3.jar
jsr305-1.3.9.jar
protobuf-java-2.2.0.jar
xpp3-1.1.4c.jar
```

Have a look over here on how to pick the correct library :

https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/Setup

If you are into maven and your soft has to run in a servlet container, try this dependency :

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
      <artifactId>google-api-client-servlet</artifactId>
      <version>1.17.0-rc</version>
    </dependency>
```

and NOT

```
 <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
      <artifactId>google-api-client-appengine</artifactId>
      <version>1.17.0-rc</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: works perfectly, had to add google-http-client-jackson2-1.17.0-rc though for JacksonFactory class.